Despite calling all changes to a Text view within a DispatchQueue.main.async call I still get the purple warning regarding Publishing changes
In my app, I am uploading a file to my server from my ObservableObject (HTTPHandler). The published strings from HTTPHandler are used by the view (UploadTemplate) to convey status and errors.
HTTPHandler, which also handles all my HTTP needs, is obviously thrown off the main queue.
So essentially the view UploadTemplate has Text views which use the string from HTTPHandler.statusMsg to keep the user informed of progress.
I embedded every change of HTTPHandler.statusMsg within a  DispatchQueue.main.async  yet I still get the warning:

Publishing changes from background threads is not allowed; make sure
to publish values from the main thread (via operators like
receive(on:)) on model updates.

I thought perhaps it's the initial setting of statusMsg when HTTPHandler is initialized perhaps? All my attempts at figuring this out has led me nowhere with the purple warning.
I've double checked that statusMsg is only within HTTPHandler, and that they're all embedded within a DispatchQueue.main.async call.
Any idea what I might be doing wrong?
import SwiftUI

struct UploadTemplate: View {
    @StateObject var xFile              = XFile()
    @EnvironmentObject var xUser        : XUser
    @State var isShowingDocumentPicker  = false
    @State var error                    = "no error"
    @State var isPerformingURL          = false
    @State var currentStatus            = ""
    @StateObject var httpHandler            = HTTPHandler()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ZStack {
                Color.teal
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
                VStack{
                    Text(xFile.fileName.isEmpty ? "No File Selected" : xFile.fileName)

                    Text(httpHandler.statusMsg)

                    Text(httpHandler.errorMsg)

                    
                    Button {
                        isShowingDocumentPicker = true
                    } label: {
                        Text("Select File")
                    }
                    .disabled(isPerformingURL)
                    
                    Button {
                        Task {
                            isPerformingURL = true
                            xFile.fileStage = .uploadOriginal
                            let request = xFile.makePostRequest(xUser: xUser, script: "uploadOrig.pl")
                            var result = await httpHandler.asyncCall(request: request, xFile: xFile)
                        }
                    }
                label: {
                    Text("Upload")
                }
                .disabled((xFile.fullPath.isEmpty || isPerformingURL))
                    
                }
                .navigationTitle("Upload Template")
                .scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
            }
            .fileImporter(
                isPresented: $isShowingDocumentPicker,
                allowedContentTypes: [.spreadsheet, .commaSeparatedText], allowsMultipleSelection: false) { result in
                    switch result {
                    case .success(let file):
                        xFile.fillXFile(fileURL: file[0], xUser: xUser)
                        
                    case .failure(let error):
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}







class HTTPHandler: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    @Published var statusMsg    = ""
    @Published var stage = FileStage.makeTicket
    @Published var errorMsg = ""
    
    func asyncCall(request: URLRequest, xFile: XFile) async -> Int {
        
        do {
            let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: request)
            guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse
            else {

                DispatchQueue.main.async { [self] in
                    statusMsg = "Unknown Error 1"
                }

                return 1
            }
            
            if httpResponse.statusCode == 200 {
                if xFile.jsonAndXFile(data: data) {
                    if xFile.hData.status == "SUCCESS" &&
                        xFile.hData.returnvalue == "SSFILEUPLOADED" {
                        xFile.fileStage = .converting
                        DispatchQueue.main.async { [self] in statusMsg = "Converting"}
                    } else if xFile.hData.status == "SUCCESS" &&
                        xFile.hData.returnvalue == "SSCONVERTING" {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async { [self] in statusMsg = String(format: "Converting %@%%", xFile.hData.message)}
                    } else if xFile.hData.status == "SUCCESS" &&
                        xFile.hData.returnvalue == "SSSTAGE1" {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async { [self] in statusMsg = String(format: "Converting %@%%", xFile.hData.message)}
                    }
                    } else {


                    DispatchQueue.main.async { [self] in
                        statusMsg = "JSON err"
                    }


                        return 4
                    }
                } else {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async { [self] in
                    statusMsg = String(format: "URL error: %d", httpResponse.statusCode)}
                    return 3
                }
            } catch {
                DispatchQueue.main.async { [self] in
                statusMsg = "async error: 2"}
                return 2
            }
        return 0
    }
    
}


Remove all the DispatchQueue calls, it is not compatible with async/await and all @MainActor to HTTPHandler

@loremipsum I hear you, but can I call @MainActor to a class that is handling HTTP requests? Aren't those inherently not on the main thread?

Don't worry about that, in a pure async/await environment it is the actor's job to decide what is gets done where. Basically at every await the actor decides what to do. You Handler is affecting UI it is perfectly fine to add @MainActor to it, it would be a different story if the @Published was not  there then the Button/Task would update the properties when the function returns not mid function.

BTW instead of the Int returns it would be much better to either throw and error or return the expected value, all those return are considered code smell
